# How to kill(if process exist) & restart a process in a single command line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, kill-process

I am in situation where i want to kill a process if exist & restart the same. How to do it?

currently i am doing this

```
killall -9 inetd && /bin/inetd
```

If inetd is not running i get this

```
killall: /bin/inetd: no process killed
```

Even though inetd is not running i want the above command to be successful.

Comment: use `;` to sequence commands, not `&&` that is a conditional.

Comment: but if some issue happens with killall, it will go ahead with /bin/inetd. I dont want this to happen. i want it to be successful even if the particular process is not found.

Comment: You said you wanted to launch `inetd` even if `killall` don't work, isn't it? So `;` will make it as both commands will be run... What do you really want?

Answer (score 0):

Use ;

```
killall -9 inetd; /bin/inetd
```

Comment: but if some issue happens with killall, it will go ahead with /bin/inetd. I dont want this to happen. i want it to be successful even if the particular process is not found.

Comment: That is not possible: "killall returns a zero return code if at least one process has been killed for each listed command, or no commands were listed and at least one process matched the -u and -Z search criteria. killall returns non-zero otherwise."